# Duda try and catch c#

Tags: c#

Cuando ingresa espacio vació o una palabra me salta el error del catch pero también me muestra los datos ingresados del ultimo usuario que registre y yo no quiero eso porque me ingreso un espacio vació o una palabra, en ese caso quiero que tire el error pero que no muestro los datos.

```
try
{
    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Blue;
    Console.WriteLine("Ingrese número de cédula (Sin guiones ni puntos). Ej:5038968");
    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
    Console.Write("\n"+"Cédula : ");
    cedula = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
}
catch
{
    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
    Console.WriteLine("\n"+"La cédula no es un dato numerico");
}
Clientes c = emp.Buscar(cedula);
```

Comment: La variable cédula te queda sucia, por eso te muestra los datos de la ultima lectura valida, te recomiendo usar una variable de ámbito dentro del try para almacenar y enviar al método emp.Buscar, de esa forma si, se genera una excepción no realiza el buscar.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

El `try` y `catch` es para identificar o capturar una exception en tiempo de ejecución, creo que el error que tienes tu es obviamente porque no se puede convertir un espacio o si no ingresas nada en un numero en el caso de tu conversion

La solucion mas logica seria identificar si lo que ingreso el usuario es distinto de vacio o `null`. Una vez que puedas verificar que los valores ingresados son correctos, ejecutar la busqueda.

```
string cedula_teclado;
cedula_teclado = Console.ReadLine();
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(cedula_teclado)) {
     //TODO BIEN
     int cedula = Convert.ToInt32(cedula_teclado);
     Clientes c = emp.Buscar(cedula);
} else {
   //Debe ingresar una cedula....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

coloca un if algo asi:

```
if NOT (console.readline()=="") 
{ 
   msgbox("aqui lo que deseas")
}
```

si no se cumple la condicion simplemente no ocurre nada